# Como converter date para datetime?

Tags: sql-server, conversão-de-tipo, cast

Tenho o seguinte caso, estou tentando converte o um campo `date` para `datetime` utilizando o *update*

```
update tb_RHContratos
set DtCadastro = cast(DtCadastro as datetime)
```

Mas alguma das data não esta formata corretamente como são muitos registro fica difícil de identificar qual data esta errada.

tenho a seguinte msg de erro

> Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 13 A conversão de um tipo de
>   dados date em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do
>   intervalo. A instrução foi finalizada

Tem como identificar qual data esta fora do intervalo com um select ou algo assim?

Comment: Qual o tipo de `DtCadastro`?

Comment: Fiz uma importação dos dados do mysql para o sqlserver, mas preciso converte para datetime.

Comment: consegui acha uma das datas erradas através da ajuda do Excel e esta no formato.. `where DtCadastro = '1162-02-26'`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez .  `DtCadastro  date`

Comment: Você pode alterar a tabela, por exemplo, adicionando colunas?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez , adicionando colunas sim , só não consegui alterar o tipo dessa coluna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o comando [`ISDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187347(v=sql.120).aspx) para verificar o que não pode ser convertido:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_RHContratos
WHERE isdate(DtCadastro) = 0
```

A dica que eu ia dar era usar `datetime2`, que suporta datas bem antigas, mas isso vai contra o que você quer, que é justamente localizar o que está com problemas.

---

**EDIT**

Tem mais uma função que você pode usar: [`TRY_CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh974669(v=sql.120).aspx).

```
SELECT DtCadastro, 
    CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(DtCadastro AS datetime) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'Ok'
    ELSE 'Falhou'
AS "Resultado da Conversão"
FROM tb_RHContratos
```

Comment: me retornou o erro ... **Mensagem 8116, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 18
Tipo de dados de argumento date inválido para o argumento 1 da função isdate.**

Comment: Achei a resposta no link => [https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187819(v=sql.120).aspx], o tipo date aceita data antigas já o datetime não por isso o erro **valor fora do intervalo**, o itervalor é **Janeiro 1, 1753, a dezembro 31, 9999**

Comment: o `TRY_CAST` é do sql server 2008 ?

Comment: Não, ele funciona a partir do 2012.